# Rewrite rule - also when folder missing

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm trying to make my PHP script url friendly. My script is in root.

These urls:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/blah
http://www.example.com/foo/bar
http://www.example.com/foo/snoopy
```

Is being rewritten with this:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/([0-9a-zA-Z-+]+)$ ./script.php?x=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is working good, and my script is getting "blah" "bar" and "snoopy" and everything into the x param.

But if I try this url:

```
http://www.example.com/foo
```

I get a 404. How do I rewrite to script.php?x=all then?

Also, I have some old requests on a similar url:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/?oldstuff=2&oldid=55
```

How can I rewrite this if oldid param is set to: `script.php?x=55`

If oldid param is not set, I want to redirect to `script.php?x=all`.  I do not care about other params here.

And still keep the top rewrites?

Comment: I ended up with this which seems to work fine:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "(.*(?:^|&))oldid=([^&]*)&?(.*)&?$"
RewriteRule "^foo/(.*)" ./script.php?x=%2 [L]
RewriteRule "^foo/?$"  /script.php?x=all [L]
RewriteRule ^foo/?([0-9a-zA-Z-+]+)$ ./script.php?x=$1 [L]`

Comment: Good job! I think the first one can be easier written as `RewriteEngine On RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" ".*(?:^|&)oldid=([^&]*)&?.*" RewriteRule "^foo/(.*)" ./script.php?x=%1 [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `http://www.example.com/foo` put a question mark after the slash in your pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/?([0-9a-zA-Z-+]+)$ ./script.php?x=$1 [L]
```

For query params look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#rewrite-query. There's examples on the manual.